# Custom TFS Check-In Policy in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, tfs, regedit

A while ago My team developed a custom TFS check-in policy that was working fine with Visual Studio 2013. & I modified the version from (12 to 14) make the same rule to work on Visual Studio 2015.

For VS2013, I had these registry keys:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies]
  "MyCheckInPolicy"="C:\\My\\MyCheckInPolicy2013.dll"
```

and

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies]
"MyCheckInPolicy"="C:\\My\\MyCheckInPolicy2013.dll"
```

For VS2015, I had Added registry key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies]
      "MyCheckInPolicy"="C:\\My\\MyCheckInPolicy2015.dll"
```

Its reflected in following registry key

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies]
    "MyCheckInPolicy"="C:\\My\\MyCheckInPolicy2015.dll"
```

And also i added the registry key

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies]
      "MyCheckInPolicy"="C:\\My\\MyCheckInPolicy2015.dll"
```

but I had no luck. I also opened my check-in policy project in VS2015 and rebuilt it (attempting to target various different frameworks: 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6) all with no luck.

Anyone know why I can't get this policy to show up in the Add Check-In Policy dialog?

Comment: are you using TFSVC or Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you referenced the correct assemblies, try following below steps to fix this issue.

1. Open your check-in policy project in VS2015
2. Remove reference **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll**
3. Add the the version of TFS 2015 reference, it should be under

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\fronpghg.gen

or you can install **[Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/14.102.0)** by running the following command in the Package Manager Console

> PM > Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient
>   -Version 14.102.0

4. Rebuild the project.
5. Register the Custom Policy in the Windows Registry
6. If your OS is 64-bit, you must add the key under the Wow6432Node instead of the path stated on MSDN:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies
7. Restart computer, start VS to check the customized check-in policy.

Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @user7014262 Have you resolved your issue by above workaround? any updates for it?

Comment: @Ansy-MSFT, Sorry for the delay in the response. And your resolution worked for me &  thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks i'll accept it as answer but am facing an issue while i validate it in one of my friend system(which has VS2015 Community Edition) the Name of the custom checkt-in policy is shows but am getting the error "Error loading the 'CustomPolicyName' policy (The policy assembly 'Custom Policy details' is not registered.). Installation instructions:" Do you know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Its a issue related to regedit & This [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2012/10/19/internal-error-loading-the-changeset-comments-checkin-policy/) workaround helped me to resolve this issue. Thanks for your support.